# How to declare a volatile list within a concurrent hashmap?

Tags: java

I have a variable:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, List<AnObjectType>> mapOfList;
```

The List as I understand is not thread safe. But I don't want to use Synchronized keyword as I actually want concurrent read access and synchronized write to the list and not blocking read and writes.

So I would normally declare `Volatile` on the variable like so:

```
volatile List<AnObjectType> varName;
```

(Although in this case I think this referers to Volatile reference on the list, but what I want is for both the list reference and the content of the list to be volatile.)

But how do I do that within a ConcurrentHashMap construct given that I don't declare the list as a variable anywhere but within a method?

i.e. List is created within method:

```
if (!mapOfList.containsKey("ListA")) {
     List<AnObjectType> listA=new ArrayList<AnObjectType>();
     mapOfList.put("ListA", listA);
}
```

and the list is accessed in another method within the same class:

```
List<AnObjectType> listA=mapOfList.get("ListA");
if (listA!=null) {
     // Do something concurrent with listA.
}
```

Sub Question: Would something like this work at all?

`ConcurrentHashMap<String,List<AtomicReference<AnObjectType>>>>`

Elaboration on the list's operations:

The list will be accessed via multiple threads reading almost constantly. Write access to the list will be triggered on certain conditions. So what I want is a concurrent access to the List's content with seldom write operations on the list's content that should be reflected by all reads after the write operation.

Comment: I don't think you're using `volatile` correctly. Also you have races in your code.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline please elaborate on the races, how can you tell with the above pseudo code? Thanks

Comment: Because combinations of thread-safe methods aren't thread-safe. 
For instance `Vector.add` and `Vector.remove` are thread-safe, they execute correctly when multiple threads call them. However if we have a swap function made from 2 remove and 2 add calls, it is not thread-safe even though it uses multiple thread-safe methods. In your case another thread can remove key "ListA" between the containsKey call in if sentence and get sentence. Thus you might get a null value there.

Comment: As far as volatile keyword goes: it would affect the list reference, not the list instance itself. JVM would issue memory barrier operation when modifying `varName` reference, but it would not issue memory barrier when modifying the arrayList object that `varName` references (adding to backing array).

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. I have corrected the Read operation to eliminate the race issue. The put is ok as it can overwrite any previous value and there is no chance two threads would issue put at the same time in my case

Comment: So to clarify as I thought the volatile on List is on the List reference and not on the content of the list. But given that the List resides in a ConcurrentHashMap it should be safe to assume the reference to List is safe? So would the declaration List<AtomicReference<AnObjectType>> work for the content of the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `ConcurrentMap#putIfAbsent` for creating the `List`, and access all lists in a lazy getter:

```
List<AnObjectType> getList(String key) {
     if (!mapOfList.containsKey(key)) {
     // This list might not end up being the one that gets returned, but
     // that's OK
         mapOfList.putIfAbsent(key, new CopyOnWriteArrayList<AnObjectType>());
     }
     return mapOfList.get(key);
}
```

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` should give you the synchronized performance you need.

Comment: Well I don't know about your method of a lazy get since actually returning null with get list is preferable than returning an empty list in this case. But CopyOnWriteArrayList seems to be the answer.

Comment: It's important that the creation of new lists is done with `putIfAbsent` otherwise your lists could get overwritten unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into [java.util.concurrent.locks](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html), particularly [ReentrantReadWriteLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html). The package Javadocs say

> The ReadWriteLock interface similarly defines locks that may be shared
>   among readers but are exclusive to writers. Only a single
>   implementation, ReentrantReadWriteLock, is provided, since it covers
>   most standard usage contexts. But programmers may create their own
>   implementations to cover nonstandard requirements.

The Javadocs for `ReentrantReadWriteLock` says

> ReentrantReadWriteLocks can be used to improve concurrency in some
>   uses of some kinds of Collections. This is typically worthwhile only
>   when the collections are expected to be large, accessed by more reader
>   threads than writer threads, and entail operations with overhead that
>   outweighs synchronization overhead.

and contains an example using a `TreeMap`.

The general idea is that you create an instance of the `ReentrantReadWriteLock` per instance of the collection. That then provides you with one `Lock` instance for read operations, and another for write operations. You then manually manage the locking during access methods.

Below is an untested implementation that should support your use case.

```
import java.util.AbstractList;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock;


public class RWList<E> extends AbstractList<E> {
    private final List<E> list = new ArrayList<E>();
    private final ReentrantReadWriteLock rwl = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
    private final Lock r = rwl.readLock();
    private final Lock w = rwl.writeLock();

    @Override
    public E set(int index, E element) {
        w.lock();
        try { return list.set(index, element); }
        finally { w.unlock(); }
    }

    @Override
    public void add(int index, E element) {
        w.lock();
        try { list.add(index, element); }
        finally { w.unlock(); }
    }

    @Override
    public E remove(int index) {
        w.lock();
        try { return list.remove(index); }
        finally { w.unlock(); }
    }

    @Override
    public E get(int index) {
        r.lock();
        try { return list.get(index); }
        finally { r.unlock(); }
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        r.lock();
        try { return list.size(); }
        finally { r.unlock(); }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vector class is synchronized ArrayList, you can also use `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList())`.

Comment: I don't want to use Synchronized because of blocking Reads.

Comment: The performance penalty is not much larger than declaring a variable volatile, which may not even work (I am not sure declaring a list volatile affects list operations at all - making them unsynchronized). 
If you don't want blocking reads then you will need to use a special implementation of List instead of ArrayList, one that implements a non-locking synchronization scheme.